# How to use different database engines in Django for testing and production

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, django-testing

I'm quite newbie in Django. I have an application in project which is developed with test driven development. In production we use MySQL as database engine, but if I run test with MySQL:

```
./manage test myapp
```

Then it absorbs too much time (2-4 mins) to create database, althought tests are quite fast (about a second).

If I use SQLite then tests requires only a few seconds, which is perfect for me. But the problem is that I often need the admin interface with my local database on MySQL.

How to make django to run tests on sqlite and launch runserver with mysql?

Now I use these settings in settings/local.py, but I should comment/uncomment lines to change database depending on what activity I do at the moment.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Use for testing
        'NAME': 'databasename.db3',
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  # Use if need admin on localserver
        # 'NAME': 'databasename',              
        'USER': 'myuser',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'somepassword',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        'TEST_CHARSET': "utf8",         #option to make tesing database with utf8
        'TEST_COLLATION': "utf8_general_ci",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option would be to check [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) for the `test` argument in `settings.py`:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'databasename.db3'
```

Though, as a side note: strictly speaking, it is not really a good idea to have different database backends for testing and for development/stage/production. You may encounter [database-specific](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes) "special" cases, that can cost you a lot of time and headache.

Comment: Your comment about database-specific cases is excellent and still relevant as of Django 3.2

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do any hacks. "--settings" - this is what you're looking for.

```
python manage.py test APP --settings settings.local
python manage.py test APP --settings settings.production
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible it's always a good idea to use the same setup in production and test. It makes for better testing. I great way to deal with tests running slowly is to use [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose). It lets you reuse previously created test databases. This can super speed up test runs. Check out [enabling database reuse](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose#enabling-database-reuse) in the docs. An example is as follows:

```
REUSE_DB=1 ./manage.py test
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually i use the following schema:

Create a two settings files for different modes

```
touch settings/production.py
touch settings/testing.py
```

On production mode

```
ln -s settings/production.py settings/__init__.py
```

On testing mode

```
ln -s settings/testing.py settings/__init__.py
```